# breaks, white-spacing? how to break an extralong word without losing text-align:justify

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following Question.

Is there a Methode to break an extra-long word without losing the `text-align:justify` ?

like breaking it in the middle or divide it in the middle in 2 words

here is the example at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jy7d431p/2/)

You can use Js or jquery as well if there is a better method :)

thank you,

Tim4497

Comment: So, did my example works for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the previous answer a little bit...

Link -> http://jsfiddle.net/jy7d431p/15/

you could just surround the word you think are way too long with an additional span tag and just assign a class name to it.

```
.user_message .break {
    text-align: justify;
    word-break:break-all;
}
```

So now only the word you select will break

EDIT.....

OK, here is the whole thing, with php.

CSS:

```
<style>
    .wrapper {
        display: table;
    }
    .wrapper span:not([class="break"]) {
        display: table-cell;
    }
    .user_message {
        text-align: justify;
    }
    .break {
        color: red; 
        word-break: break-all;
    }
</style>
```

HTML AND PHP

```
<?php

    $myText = "Sed vitae dui porta, rhoncus metus ac, malesuada diam. Duis ipsum ipsum, blandit ut ante quis, ullamcorper auctor purus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean vitae maximus nunc. Sed vitae ligula eget lectus interdum bibendum eu et ex. Pellentesque in odio quis nulla scelerisque dignissim non vitae turpis. Suspendisse magna turpis, lobortis eget imperdiet varius, hendrerit sed nunc. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Fusce vel tellus sollicitudin, volutpat eros eget, maximus enim. Pellentesque et convallis orci. Suspendisse eu tempus elit. Nulla facilisi. Integer interdum risus massa, eu ultrices tortor iaculis ut.";
    $myWords = explode(" ", $myText);
    $output = "";
    $maxLen = 10;
    $totalWords = count($myWords)-1;

    for ($i = 0; $i <= $totalWords; $i++) {
        if (strlen($myWords[$i]) > $maxLen) {
            $myWords[$i] = "<span class=\"break\">".$myWords[$i]."</span>";
        }
        $output .= $myWords[$i].($i < $totalWords?" ":"");
    }

?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="user_name" style="color:#FF7000">Test</span>
    <span>:</span>
    <span class="user_message"><?=$output;;?></span>
</div>
```

There you have it Sr. please let me know if this works for you or not.

Comment: Adding those spans would require additional JavaScript.

Comment: True unless you are creating the content with a server language like PHP. In both cases, a simple function could be created in php or jquery to solve that small issue. Then a minimun character's length could be specified.

Comment: hmm im not the prof in js, but i can try it myself and when it doesn't work i will ask again!

Comment: PHP, thats great. If you need help, let me know and I could give you a hand.

Comment: that would be awesome, I don't even know that you can do those things with php :)

Comment: SO, did my example helps?!

Comment: Sorry i was busy, yes it works but i think in the near future i have to realize it with javascript (: thank you

Comment: OK, good to know, just one good tip, don't depend too much on javascript or jquery to handle text content, at the end is not good for your website SEO, just because the text i's been handle by java script or jquery and the search engines just read rendered html and not what ever happens after the page loads. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
.user_message {
   word-break: break-all;
}
```

Link -> [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jy7d431p/3/)

Comment: i had the same idea, but it breaks also the short words, this will interrupt the reading-flow